# Don't have access for anything on MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm using MySQL for the first time, on Ubuntu. I previously made the database `vq`, which is practically empty (I don't mind deleting everything; I still have the SQL file to create it).

Now, I try to access the database again:

```
james@ubuntu~$ mysql vq
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'vq'
james@ubuntu~$ mysql -u root -p vq
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I reset the root password using some other instructions, so I'm using the correct password.

```
james@ubuntu~$ mysql
```

[snip]

```
mysql> create database dummy;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'dummy'
mysql> \q
Bye
james@ubuntu~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I just reinstalled it using [these](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265685/how-to-reinstall-mysql) instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Try following:
1) Stop MySQL service
2) Run it with `mysqld -skip-grant-tables`
3) Log into it with `mysql -u root`
4) Set again new password

```
> use mysql;
> update user set password=PASSWORD('new_password') where user = 'root';
> flush privileges;
> quit;
```

5) Restart MySQL service
6) Log in with new password `mysql -u root -p`

Following steps helped someone with same problem 
[here](http://forum.php.pl/lofiversion/index.php/t140773.html)

Comment: Step 3 fails with `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. I did:  
`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`  `sudo mysqld -skip-grant-tables`  `sudo mysql -u root`